# Video recorded through input tag on iOS in my react application is blurred / pixelated

Tags: html, reactjs

I am using the following code to access the native camera to record a video from mobile in my reactjs application:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture />;
```

It works fine for android devices but on iOS, the video seems to be pixelated / blurred (can be seen even when the recorder is opened).

Not sure what the issue may be here.